# how do i loop through this object and insert each line into a mysql database table

Tags: python, mysql, csv, gnupg

My question follows after the code:

```
[root@localhost dest]# python 
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


>>> import csv
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> import gnupg

>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/chefgit/Desktop/.gnupg")
>>> file = open("/home/chefgit/Desktop/csv/dest/file_100.gpg", 'r+')
>>> decrypt = gpg.decrypt_file(file)

>>> import StringIO
>>> csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(decrypt))

>>> import MySQLdb
>>> connect = MySQLdb.connect\
('localhost', 'chefgit', 'password', 'python_db_1')

>>> cursor = connect.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

   1L

>>> print (cursor.fetchone())

    ('5.1.73',)

>>> sql = "INSERT INTO python_db_1

('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'ip_address')VALUES\ 
('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"

>>> csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(decrypt)
>>> for row in csv_input:
...        if csv_input.line_num == 1:
...              continue
...        cursor.execute(sql '%row')

     File "<stdin>", line 4
     cursor.execute(sql '%row')
                        ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am having a tough time figuring out how to loop through the rows and load them into a MySQL database table.

I have to loop through the csv_input variable (obtained from `StringIO.StringIO(decrypt)`) and read line by line and load the data into a database table. I cannot read it from a file. I must read it from the object in memory. That is the requirement placed on me by my boss.

Comment: Have you tried using the .executemany() function? I don't really understand what you think you're doing with cursor.execute(sql '%row'). You're passing two separate arguments to execute() with a space between them. Are you trying to format the sql string? Or are you trying to concatenate whatever 'row' is with the sql string?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I went for lunch and just got back. I am totally new to python. I started this job and on the very first day they asked me to write a script in python. They don't care that i don't know.They say go look it up. So I'm just trying my best here. I will try the  executemany() and get back here with the results.Thank you again for responding.

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate whatever "row" is with the sql string.

Comment: Since you set csv_input to be read as a string, your variable "row" is already the string you want. So, you can concatenate them by simply using cursor.execute(sql + row)